# How to run code ONLY if user exit the app?

Tags: android

I tried creating a class with the wanted code with onPause and extend it on all activities on the app but that will be called every time another activity comes into foreground I want code runs only if the user exit the app

How can I do that?

Comment: What about using the onDestroy event in your main activity?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, You can listen to onDestroy() event of your main activity as mentioned and then start service perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

In short you can't really know when the app is closed. It is never really closed by the user, the system is in charge of that stuff. The user is just in charge of whether or not it is currently being displayed. So, the onPause/onDestory of your activities may be what you want.

May I ask what you are trying to accomplish? There might be a better way such as using an alarm to schedule something to happen every so often.

Comment: I want to set editor.putString("done",""); when the user exits the app

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: basically I want to run a code when the user runs the app BTW when navigating from activity 1 for example to activity 2 activity 1 will be finished (I have 7 activity's) and I only want one activity running

Comment: So you want to add the flag to your intent that clears the backstack. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. Not write to shared preferences.